# Como retornar o último valor de uma string sql?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso utilizar o último caractere de uma string o G. Como que eu pego ele com sql server?

```
SET @VALOR = '0000050529-G'
```

Quero pegar a letra *G*

Answer (score 10):

Use a função [`RIGHT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ela retorna o(s) N caractere(s) à direita, a quantidade é informada pelo segundo argumento.

```
SET @VALOR = RIGHT('0000050529-G', 1)
```